# Button click event is not fired in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on jQuery Mobile.

I have a view in which I am displaying the collabsible  list which is being loaded dynamically. Hence my jQuery file gets the JSON data, runs the loop around `$('mylist').append(..data for each row..)`.

Now in every collapsible item, I am adding a button which has to run a JavaScript function alongwith the parameters. This is where I am stucked. Somehow the event is not fired on click. Is it because of the fact that no event is generated or the the parameters I am passing in variables are the main problem.

```
$('#main')
  .bind("pageshow", function (event) { 
    var cusid = getUrlVars()["cusid"]; 
    var locid = getUrlVars()["locid"]; 
    $.getJSON("localhost/mserv/Offers.php";, function(data) { 
      $.each(data, function(index, offer){ 
        $('#cat_list').append("<div align='center' data-role='collapsible'><h3>offer.name</h3><p>offer.price</p><input type= 'button' onclick='addItem("+offer.id+",'"+offer.name+"',"+offer.price+")' value='Add To Cart'></div>"); 
      }); 
    $('#cat_list').collapsibleset('refresh'); 
  });
```

Comment: <pre>$('#main').bind("pageshow", function (event){
 var cusid = getUrlVars()["cusid"];
 var locid = getUrlVars()["locid"];
 $.getJSON("http://localhost/mserv/Offers.php", function(data) {
  
  $.each(data, function(index, offer){
            $('#cat_list').append("<div align='center' data-role='collapsible'><h3>offer.name</h3><p>offer.price</p><input type= 'button' onclick='addItem("+offer.id+",'"+offer.name+"',"+offer.price+")' value='Add To Cart'></div>");
  });
  $('#cat_list').collapsibleset('refresh');
        }); <code>

Comment: @Baxethov When you have code to add, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10421647/edit) your question.

Comment: `$.getJSON("localhost/mserv/Offers.php";, function(data) {` is invalid, the semi-colon (`;`) must be removed for this block of code to correctly be parsed.

Comment: Is there a function named `addItem` that is in the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea what might be the problem, though actually you didn't give enough information (especially the code you use):

jQuery mobile always adds elements to the DOM via AJAX. If you want to add event-listeners to elements that are added to the DOM via AJAX, then you need to use `on()` instead of `click()`, for example.

So replace

```
$('clickableElement').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

with

```
$('clickableElement').on('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

This way you bind the click-eventlistener to your element, even if it did not exist when the DOM was initially loaded (first call of your page), as soon as it is added to the DOM via AJAX.

Comment: so this means that <input ....... onclick="someFunc()"/> doesnot work in this scenario? And do we now have any limitation for passing arguments to functions in jquery mobile?

Comment: Not sure about this both. I posted my answer before you posted your code. Anyway, I replaced `live` with `on` in my example above, as `live` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: You did replace `.live()` with `.on()` but you didn't replace it with the delegated version of the function. `$(SELECTOR).live(EVENT, EVENT-HANDLER);` is the same as: `$(document).on(EVENT, SELECTOR, EVENT-HANDLER);`. The way you are using `.on()` is the same as using `.bind()`. And since the OP is using inline JS the binding will occur so event delegation should not be necessary.